# Redefining static const values in derived classes C++

Tags: c++, static, constants, hierarchy

If I create a static const in the base class of my hierarchy, can I redefine its value in a derived class?

edit:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
  static const int i = 1;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  static const int i = 2;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Base::i == " << Base::i << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Derived::i == " << Derived::i << std::endl;  

  Base * ptr;

  ptr= new Derived;

  std::cout<< "ptr=" << ptr->i << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

...`ptr` refers to `Base::i`, which is undesirable.

Comment: The edit (by the OP) has changed this question _a lot_. It now uses the source code of my answer to the original question to create an entirely new one, which is really about using a pointer to access static members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access via `ptr` to static members is via its declared type `Base *` and not its runtime type (sometimes `Base *`, sometimes `Derived *`).  You can see this with the following trivial extension of your program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    static const int i = 1;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    static const int i = 2;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Base::i == " << Base::i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Derived::i == " << Derived::i << std::endl;  

    Base *b_ptr = new Derived;
    std::cout<< "b_ptr=" << b_ptr->i << std::endl;

    Derived *d_ptr = new Derived;
    std::cout<< "d_ptr=" << d_ptr->i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Base::i == 1
Derived::i == 2
b_ptr=1
d_ptr=2
```

Answer (score 3):

No. It's `const`, so you cannot modify its value.

But you can declare a new `static const` of the same name for the derived class, and define its value there.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
  static const int i = 1;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  static const int i = 2;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Base::i == " << Base::i << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Derived::i == " << Derived::i << std::endl;  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Xploit Yes, right. Of course a `const_cast` enables you to modify the value. And it does that even when there is no derived class around.

Comment: note that members fns in Base will will continue still access the base static const, but there are ways around that as well.

Comment: `const_cast` for a really constant data will cause undefined behavior, when you try to change it, won't it?

Comment: @juleekwin Yes, of course. As I said, `Derived::i` is a new variable.

Comment: @jogojapan +1 (reluctantly) Your comment about using `const_cast` makes me want to downvote you instead. As Kiril observes, applying `const_cast` to truly `const` members invokes UB

Comment: @Prætorian True. (Which is why it is a comment and won't become part of the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

you must initiate the const memember variable in the Constructor member initialization list.

you can not modify the const variable.

Comment: Remember the question was about a static member.